# How to open XBRL document in android

Tags: android

How to open XBRL document in our android app?any third party library available or is it availble already in android?

Answer (score 1):

It seems nothing android specific is available, at least I couldn't find anything. Since Android development is done in Java, you could try integrating an existing java xbrl implementation into your project, usually it should work.

http://www.xbrlapi.org/

looks promising. If you're successful, please post a short review here, as I can imaging, this concerns several other people as well.